# Matching a string containing special characters with regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line in my file which contains the following string

```
$print = "SM_sdo_debugss_cxct6_CSCTM_4 \csctm_gen[4]_ctm_i_nctm_I_csctm  (4+5)";
$my_meta = '\csctm_gen[4]_ctm_i_nctm_I_csctm';
print "I got this\n" if($print =~ /\Q$my_meta\E/);
```

But it's not able to find the `$my_meta` string in `$print`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your first string is in double quotes, so backslash escape sequences are processed.

`\cs` stands for Ctrl-S, which can also be written `chr(19)` or `"\x13"`.

Your second string is in single quotes, which ignores backslash escapes (apart from `\\` and `\'`).

So your regex ends up looking for a 3-character sequence `\` `c` `s`, but your target string contains a single byte `0x13`.

To fix this, either write `"... \\cs ..."` in your first string (the first backslash escapes the second one), or use single quotes for your first string (`'... \cs ...'`).

Comment: But i dont have any control on editing my $my_meta, it will come from processing some other file. I want to place a condition on my regex which will take any string with special characters as search string. Have I made my point clear? Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekDas No, it's not very clear. Are you saying you want to interpret some backslash sequences in `$my_meta` but not others? In any case, if you want help with the real problem, show your real code.

Comment: In actual scenario the $my_meta will come from some other script and the content of $my_meta can have backslashes which I will search in a file and get the respective line number. So I can not edit the content of $my_meta as you suggested in your solution.  I have to do something in `if($print =~ /\Q$my_meta\E/);` statement to catch the $my_meta string

Comment: I didn't suggest editing `$my_meta`. Again, show your real code.

Comment: Yes The code works on my file. As it is in the company policy I can't share the exact file. But your codes worked after I replace the double quotes with single, Thanks @melpomene